# Regarding python list with reference

Tags: python, list, reference

Here is the example:

```
>>> x = ["a","b","c"]
>>> yy = [x] * 3
>>> yy
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
>>> yy[0][0] = 'A'
>>> yy
[['A', 'b', 'c'], ['A', 'b', 'c'], ['A', 'b', 'c']]
>>>
```

When I do `yy[0][0] = 'A'`, it replaced to all the first element of the sub-list. What I got from here is when I do `[x] * 3`, it creates some reference to list `x` but not sure how really it works. Could some one please explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[x]*3` creates 3 references to the same list.  You have to create three different lists:

```
>>> yy = [list('abc') for _ in range(3)]
>>> yy[0][0]='A'
>>> yy
[['A', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

The first line creates a new list using a list comprehension that loops 3 times.

Using `id()`, you can visualize that the same list reference is duplicated:

```
>>> x=list('abc')
>>> id(x)
67297928                                  # list object id
>>> yy=[x]*3                              # create a list with x, duplicated...
>>> [id(i) for i in yy]
[67297928, 67297928, 67297928]            # same id multipled
>>> yy = [list('abc') for _ in range(3)]  
>>> [id(i) for i in yy]
[67298248, 67298312, 67297864]            # three different ids
```